# How to find incompatible script by `grep` when update mysql?

Tags: mysql, grep

I am updating mysql from 5.1 to 5.5.
At this [post](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html), mentioned:

> In MySQL 5.5.3, several changes were made to alias resolution in multiple-table DELETE statements so that it is no longer possible to have inconsistent or ambiguous table aliases.

Because Mysql didn't provide tools to help us to revise the incompatible places.Then, I need to use `grep` to find `DELETE FROM tablename AS` in my php files and revise to `DELETE FROM tablename USING tablename AS`.

My trial:`grep -r -o -i -a 'delete from \w\{1,\} as \w\{1,\}'` /var/www
but failed.

How to find `DELETE FROM tablename AS`?

Comment: It Works For Me™ What makes you say it failed?

Comment: @Schwern,when there's more space within `delete from tablename AS`

Comment: Then use `grep -Eoia 'delete from\s+\w+\s+as\s+\w+' /var/www`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,can I add `-r` as `grep -Eroia ...`?

Comment: I am using centos 7. `-r` means  recursive,`-E` means extended regular  expression.

Comment: Ok, so, `grep -rEoia 'delete from\s+\w+\s+as\s+\w+' /var/www` or `grep -rEoia 'delete from[ \t]+[^ \t]+[ \t]+as[ \t]+[^ \t]+' /var/www`?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting the answer if it turned out useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -rEoia 'delete from[ \t]+[^ \t]+[ \t]+as[ \t]+[^ \t]+' /var/www
```

Or,

```
grep -rEoia 'delete from[ \t]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[ \t]+as[ \t]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+' /var/www
```

In regex, `\w` usually stands for letters, digits and a `_` char.

The `-E` option is necessary to support `+` quantifier. If you can't use it, use

```
grep -roia 'delete from[ \t]\{1,\}[a-zA-Z0-9_]\{1,\}[ \t]\{1,\}as[ \t]\{1,\}[a-zA-Z0-9_]\{1,\}' /var/www
```